# A random variable of a CDF is proportional to x on the interval [0, 1] and = 0 for x<0 and = 1 for x>1. What is a formula for this CDF?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm aware of the conditions of a CDF. 
to be a cumulative distribution: it is always nonnegative, when x→−∞ x→−∞ it tends to 0, when x→+∞ it tends to 1, and it is right-continuous .

Comment: _Note_: this is the CDF of the [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) over [0,1], classically denoted by _U_ (0,1).

Comment: $F(x)=\min(1,\max(0,x))$ works but is not as simple to read or understand as the definition in three pieces

Answer (score 1):

The CDF is proportional to $x$ if it has the form $F(x)=cx$, for some constant $c$. You need that, for $x<0$, $F(x)=0$, and for $x>1$, $F(x)=1$.

What constant $c$ makes it such that $F(0)=0$, $F(1)=1$?

$F(0)=c\cdot0=0$ always.

$F(1)=c\cdot1=1$, so we need $c$ to be equal to 1.